# Email automation using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, gmail

How do I select the latest unread mail from a specific mailer using Selenium.
The class/id identifier are specific to particular mails, so its resulting in hardcoding to use these identifiers.

Comment: Please be more specific when asking questions .if you are looking for say gmail latest unread mail as an example then its fine but if you are looking for a specific mailer which is used at your organization then its hard for anybody to explain.So please explain what exactly you want

Comment: I am looking for the latest unread mail in gmail from a particular mailer. Suppose I am looking for mails from XYZ and the latest mail sent by XYZ to my gmail account.

Comment: yeah now thats specific and can be done wait some time i will post an exmaple regarding that hope that will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please find the solution for your question this is working exactly as per your recent comment

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\eclipseProject\\StackOverFlow\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?");

    // gmail login
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("your gmail username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("your gmail password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

    // some optional actions for reaching gmail inbox
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Google apps']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("gb23")).click();

    // now talking un-read email form inbox into a list
    List<WebElement> unreademeil = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='zF']"));

    // Mailer name for which i want to check do i have an email in my inbox 
    String MyMailer = "Udacity";

    // real logic starts here
    for(int i=0;i<unreademeil.size();i++){
        if(unreademeil.get(i).isDisplayed()==true){
            // now verify if you have got mail form a specific mailer (Note Un-read mails)
            // for read mails xpath loactor will change but logic will remain same
            if(unreademeil.get(i).getText().equals(MyMailer)){
                System.out.println("Yes we have got mail form " + MyMailer);
                // also you can perform more actions here 
                // like if you want to open email form the mailer
                break;
            }else{
                System.out.println("No mail form " + MyMailer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

and the result shown in console in eclipse is

```
Yes we have got mail form Udacity
```

Hope this helps you what you are looking for

Comment: That helps a lot!.. thank you..
need more.. How do I open the unread mail??
the xpath/class/id will change whenever there is a new email.

Comment: No in gmail for unread mails xpath will be one and for unread mail xpath will be one as u can see for unread i have used single xpath which represents all unread mail in the inbox if you want single xpath for unread then please update xptah to this By.xpath("//*[@class='yP']") also if it reaqlly helped you then please mark this as your answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

Besides the down-votes: There is no common way to do that. This totally depends on your Web-Mailer. Normally unread mails have some special classes attached to them. So what I do in situations like this, is to look for them, build an XPath (which can bei either easiely tested in the chrome dev tools search text field, or with the Chrome extension "XPath Helper") and either click tem and delete them one by one, or - if present - select a checkbox in the same row. The XPath expressions tend to be relativly large, but also flexible enough.

The biggest problem is, that Web-Mailer often tend to change, so you will need to keep track. Which can be unnerving.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to go through GUI options better using using the JAVAX MAIL API. I have similar kind of problem, sorted. So, using the JAVAX MAIL API and Java code below:

```
  public GmailUtils(String username, String password, String server, 
  EmailFolder 
    emailFolder) throws Exception {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
    props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imap");
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, "<your email>", "<your password>");

    Folder folder = store.getFolder(emailFolder.getText());
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    System.out.println("Total Messages:" + folder.getMessageCount());
    System.out.println("Unread Messages:" + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());

    messages = folder.getMessages();

    for (Message mail : messages) {
        if (!mail.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN) &&  mail.getFrom()[0]= <emailer address>)
 // unread email and from the specific sender
 {          System.out.println("**********************************");
            System.out.println("MESSAGE : \n");

            System.out.println("Subject: " + mail.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From: " + mail.getFrom()[0]);
            System.out.println("To: " + mail.getAllRecipients()[0]);
            System.out.println("Date: " + mail.getReceivedDate());
            System.out.println("Size: " + mail.getSize());
            System.out.println("Flags: " + mail.getFlags());
            System.out.println("ContentType: " + mail.getContentType());                
            System.out.println("Body: \n" + getEmailBody(mail));
            System.out.println("Has Attachments: " + hasAttachments(mail));

        }
    }
}
```